# How do you model a table for unit conversion?

Tags: database, modeling

I'm looking to create a db model of various units and their relation to each other.  For instance, 36 inches = 3 feet = 1 yard = .9144 meters etc.  This table would also store cups in ounces, pounds, kg, grams, cm and all sorts of measurements.

How do you do this?  I was thinking about something like this:

```
Amount | Units | ConversionFactor | ConversionUnits
1      | foot  | 12               | inches
1      | yard  | 36               | inches
```

But frankly, this seems like a terrible idea.  Trying to figure out how many feet in a yard would be very convoluted, and I don't think I could ever store all the conversions I need.

What other ideas are there?  I know this is a solved problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to store conversion units in a database? They're not going to change.

Comment: Ahh, how simple this would be if you guys took up the metric system. But that's another discussion.

Comment: Because I want to store foods & their nutritional information.  I want to enter a recipe in grams and switch it to ounces whenever I feel like it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store [conversions to SI units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units), not to other non-metric units. Then you can convert between units in without needing to know the explicit conversion.

```
Unit         | Class      | Base Unit Multiplier
------------------------------------------------------
foot         | length     | 0.304800610
yard         | length     | 0.914401830
square foot  | area       | 0.092903040
...
```

So 14 feet in yards is:

```
14 feet * 0.304800610 = 4.26720854 meters
4.26720854 meters * 0.914401830⁻¹ = 4.66666667 yards
```

Comment: -1 for SI units - this solution is only likely to be useful in situations where SI units are the norm, otherwise it is likely to introduce rounding errors (if converting between feet and yards, for example). Counter-balanced by +1 for including Class.

Comment: @Mark - SI units *are* the norm (for 6 billion of us, anyway :) Besides, you may get rounding errors with imperial units too, e.g.:  
 `1 foot = 0.000189393939394 miles`.

Comment: which Portland are you in? :) I would normally suggest picking the smallest possible conversion unit as the base unit.

Comment: Is there any way to extend this approach to include conversions such as temperature (F-C, and vice versa), which are not related by a single multiplier? (See follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143863/unit-conversion-table-in-sql).)

Answer (score 4):

Pick a base unit for each [dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) you are interested in (read that wiki page, it'll be useful). For example, if most of your data is in SI units, you would pick kilogram for mass, second for time, metre for distance, and so on. If most of your data is in US units, pick units from the [US customary units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units), for example pound for mass, foot for length, second for time.

Then store, for each actual unit you want to be able to handle, the conversion factor to the dimensionally-appropriate base unit. So if you choose foot as your base unit of distance, store

```
Unit    Dimension    Factor
Foot    Distance     1
Metre   Distance     3.28084
Mile    Distance     5280
```

To actually do a conversion, once you've checked that the dimensions match, simply multiply by the `Factor` of the source unit, and divide by the `Factor` of the destination unit. For example, to get from metres to miles, multiply by 3.28084, then divide by 5280.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE UnitConversion
(
    [FromUnit] NVARCHAR(100),
    [ToUnit] NVARCHAR(100),
    [FromOffset] DECIMAL(29,10),
    [Multiplicand] DECIMAL(29,10),
    [Denominator] DECIMAL(29,10),
    [ToOffset] DECIMAL(29,10)
)
```

ToUnit = (FromUnit + FromOffset) * Multiplicand / Denominator + ToOffset

Comment: Could you explain what the offset fields do? Perhaps an example or two would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

I think the original post's proposed schema is fine, apart from not including Class (as in Seth's answer) - you don't want to try to convert between pints and inches.

Converting between two units where neither of them is the conversion unit is simply achieved by retrieving both units' conversion records and dividing one factor by the other (eg. 36/12 = 3 feet in a yard).

If you are particularly concerned about accuracy, you could ensure that all units for a given class have entries for all other units in the same class - this strikes me as overkill, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ConvertUnits()
Dim input As Double = Double.Parse(txtInput.Text)
Dim result As Double = 0

Select Case cmbUnit1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Case "Mg"
        Select Case cmbUnit2.SelectedItem.ToString()
            Case "Mg"
                result = input
            Case "g"
                result = input * 1000
            Case "Kg"
                result = input * 1000000
            Case "Tonne"
                result = input * 1000000000
            Case "Grain"
                result = input * 0.0154324
            Case "Ounce"
                result = input * 28349.5
            Case "Pound"
                result = input * 453592
            Case "Stone"
                result = input * 6350293.18
        End Select
    Case "g"
        ' Code for converting from g to other units
    Case "Kg"
        ' Code for converting from Kg to other units
    Case "Tonne"
        ' Code for converting from Tonne to other units
    Case "Grain"
        ' Code for converting from Grain to other units
    Case "Ounce"
        ' Code for converting from Ounce to other units
    Case "Pound"
        ' Code for converting from Pound to other units
    Case "Stone"
        ' Code for converting from Stone to other units
End Select

lblResult.Text = result.ToString()
```

End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).