# unit conversion table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I want to implement unit-conversion functionality in a database for units of mass, volume, temperature, etc. My background is in software development, so I naturally lean towards creating a bunch of User-Defined Functions for this task. But I have sneaking suspicion there is a more "SQLish" way of accomplishing this.

The table-based method, such as the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956044/how-do-you-model-a-table-for-unit-conversion) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495813/sql-custom-unit-conversion) would be excellent, but I see no simple way of extending this approach for units which are not related by a single multiplier, such as temperature (F-to-C, C-to-F) or atomic mass (kgmol-to-kg). I have seen multi-step approaches (such as the one described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18556/8521)), but these seem far too convoluted to be useful.

Am I missing something obvious here, or are functions really the only way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to stick with UDFs. The primary motivation for that decision was that the complexity of the table-based approach didn't seem to be justified, given the infrequency of this task. Also, several of the functions (e.g. `ConvertMass()`) are dependent on subqueries (to determine the atomic weight of a given component, for example). So UDFs seemed like the most prudent way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To handle temperature conversions, your conversion table should have a multiplier and an offset.  For F --> C, for instance, the offset would be -32 and the multiplier 5/9.

If you know all the possible units in advance, then a table-based message works fine.  However, if you want a fully flexible system such as meters^5*liters to inches^5*gallons, then you'll want a basse units table and a user defined function to do the conversion.  This function would probably use a recursive cte to parse the units expression.  All this would be rather complicated, so hopefully you have a complete list of units.

Comment: The database is simple enough that the recursive approach wont be necessary. As for temperature, the solution isn't as simple as you suggest, because the offset and the multiplier have to be applied in *opposite* order depending on whether you're converting F-to-C or C-to-F (add-then-multiply, or multiply-then-add, respectively). There doesn't appear to be a simple way to store that extra information (the recipe order) in a table.

Comment: The factor, offset for F--> is 5/9, -32.  For C-->F, they are 9/5, 32*5/9.  So, x degrees F is (x-32)*5/9.  And, y degrees C is (y-17.77778)*9/5.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Very nice. (Although a slight typo in your comment -- it should read C is (y `+` 17.77778)*9/5)

Comment: But I'm still stuck on atomic mass conversions, where the multiplier/factor (from kgmol-to-kg) is not a constant but rather depends on the atomic weight of a given substance.

Comment: You are getting to more complex types of conversions.  For this, you either need to include another factor (atomic weight) that gets included in select formulas.  Or, you start down the path of a user defined function, so you can look up the atomic weight as needed.